# DOMParser in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, typescript, dom

I have a library implementation that relies on DOMParser to parse XML. This works well in the browser, but obviously cannot work with Node. I tried to use JSDOM with their own DOMParser, but there are actually subtle differences in the implementations that cause my tests to fail.

I am looking at alternative domhandler, specifically htmlparser2. What I need to do at a basic level is replicate this behavior in htmlparser2:

```
const parser = new DOMParser();
const root: Document = parser.parseFromString(xmlString, "application/xml");
```

I have tried this with htmlparser2:

```
const res = parseDOM(xmlString, { xmlMode: true });
```

But this returns type: Node[] instead of a Document. I can't for the life of me find documentation from htmlparser2 that will produce a Document from XML, or a way to convert my Node[] into a document.

It seems like the problem is in my browser tests (mocking up a browser in testing with Karma) the tests fail because of the JSDom code.

Even with code like this:

```
let parser;
if(true){
    parser = new DOMParser();
}else{
    const JsDomParser = new JSDOM().window.DOMParser;
    parser = new JsDomParser();
}
```

The tests fail. I have to actually comment out the JSDOM stuff to get my tests to pass. Maybe there is an incompatiability with the browser?

Any help accomplishing this as a drop in DOMParser replacement would be much appreciated.

Comment: I prefer using [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) for such tasks. I'm however not sure if it solves your problem

Comment: I would love to, it just seems like their DOMParser implementation differs slightly from the browser so it seems to be off the table for me

Comment: @Keimeno it actually seems like my tests fail because of the jsdom stuff. Even when the code is unreachable, it looks like it breaks browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

In Saxon-JS we use the xml DOM implementation from https://github.com/xmldom/xmldom and it works well for us, though we haven't done a recent comparison with other options and our use is a little specialised, for example it's primarily read-only. Also we don't actually use it for parsing, for that we use github/isaacs/sax-js -- and we tweaked both products to improve the level of XML conformance in edge cases.

I don't think we've encountered any compatibility issues between xmldom under node.js, and the XML DOM implementations in the browsers.